Profraw file not generating for android build
So basically i want to generate a code coverage report for my android builds, using the jniLibs files (.so files), but here it is not generating anything.
I followed the same approach in linux and macOS it worked there, but here it is not generating.
i tried running
LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=“default.profraw” am start -n “world.tally.twcoremaintest/world.tally.twcoremain.TWMainActivityKernelAndroid” -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
inside the adb shell aslo, after setting LLVM_PROFILE_FILE as env variable, but still it is not generating the profraw file
Is this correct approach for android?
Please Help.
